# How can I rename Altium Library file and apply source change for each component?

Tags: altium, library, cad

I want to change the name of the library files in my Altium Project (inside the folder "Libraries" you can find .SchLib and .PcbLib). I can righ click them and select the rename option. That works but then, in the schematics, I would have to select component by component and change the field "source" from their properties in order to refer to the new library name. Otherways, Altium will not find where those components are, due to the change in the library name. Is there any way of renaming the .PcbLib and .SchLib avoiding selecting the new file in each source property for each component in the schematics?

Note: I know I could rename the file and then open it and do "Update components" but this will move all the designators in the screen and change parameters from the property panel that are inherent from that component but I could have change for a specific use of one in the schematic.

[image]